# How to get id query params in angular2

Tags: angular

**localhost:4200/app/2**

here app-appComponent.
2-id which takes as dynamic.

here we want to get the id dynamically from the url ...

how to get the parameter value 2 in app component directly from url when bootstrapping the app...

appreciated answer for this problem.

Comment: you read it via the router parameters

Comment: we are not using routelink and route outlet concept....when loading the application, we need to get appropriate id by this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) in appcomponent.ts

Answer (score 5):

On you `ngOnInit` you need to do this stuff.
First of all import `ActivatedRoute` and inject it into component

```
     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          const prodId = params['id'];
       }
     }
```

And do whatever you want with this parameter.

Same if we need it only once we can use this snippet in `ngOnInit`

```
const prodId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Comment: If you only need it when first starting the app, then you don't need to subscribe. you can just use: this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params

Comment: we done it but it getting "NaN" in console for that id.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, but this id may change within component i think, so we can restart logic inside using it.

Comment: not working with angular 6

Answer (score 1):

Use `angular/router` component by passing params from routes defined in your main app component.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';   

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => console.log(res.id)); // res.id where id is the name of the route parameter declared in app component routing section
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: this is not working in my case..can u suggest me some better way..Thanks in advance.. I have angular 6